# Emacs ispell error when accepting words for local file dictionary

Tags: emacs, spelling, ispell

In every  `.tex` file, when I type `A` (shift a) to accept a new word, I get the error message `Wrong type argument: sequencep, 1` in the minibuffer or in the message buffer:

```
ispell-add-per-file-word-list: Wrong type argument: sequencep, 1
```

If I  add, at the bottom of the file, a line  similar to the following:

```
% LocalWords:  hello
```

I get can (A)ccept a limited number of words, by and large up to 50 characters of new words, that is up to the end of the line. Then I get the same error again. If I add another line like the previous, therefore:

```
% LocalWords:  hello <words added by ispell ...>
% LocalWords:  again
```

I can go on again up to the end of the line. Thereafter the error shows again.

As for my init file, I have these apparently innocent lines:

```
(setenv "DICPATH" (concat exec-directory "../hunspell/dict"))
(setq-default ispell-program-name
  (concat exec-directory "../hunspell/hunspell.exe"))
(setq ispell-extra-args '("-t"))
(setq ispell-local-dictionary-alist
      '(
        (nil       "[A-Za-z]" "[^A-Za-z]" "[']" nil ("-d" "en_US") nil utf-8)
        ("english" "[A-Za-z]" "[^A-Za-z]" "['.]"    nil ("-d" "en_GB") nil utf-8)

        ("italian"
"[A-Z\300\301\310\311\314\315\322\323\331\332a-z\340\341\350\351\354\355\363\371\372]"
 "[^A-Z\300\301\310\311\314\315\322\323\331\332a-z\340\341\350\351\354\355\363\371\372]"
        "[-.]" nil ("-d" "it_IT") nil iso-8859-1)

        ))
```

In summary, whenever it is time to start a new line of the local file dictionary, `ispell-add-per-file-word-list` gets into troubles.

Comment: How about trying Aspell instead to see if that gives you less problems?  `(setq-default ispell-program-name "c:/Program Files/Aspell/bin/aspell.exe")`  --  http://aspell.net/win32/ -- the base application is `Aspell-0-50-3-3-Setup.exe` and the English dictionary is `Aspell-en-0.50-2-3.exe` and the Italian dictionary is `aspell-it-0.50-2-3.exe`

Comment: Here is a link to a sample function I use to change Aspell dictionaries on the fly:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/22190123/2112489

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This suggested workaround](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-auctex/2013-12/msg00010.html) fixes the problem for me. Excerpting it here for posterity, the workaround is to add the following to your Emacs start-up code:

```el
(add-hook 'TeX-mode-hook #'(lambda ()
                             (setq-local comment-padding " ")))
```

The root cause is an Emacs bug that [has subsequently been fixed](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-auctex/2013-12/msg00011.html). So this problem should go away entirely in Emacs 24.4 and later.